# How to use enable_shared_from_this in template functions?

Tags: c++, c++17, boost-asio, shared-ptr

I am trying to use std::enabled_shared_from_this function in a template function but I keep getting message bad_weak_ptr error in calling shared_from_this() in a class.

```
template<T>
class A: public std::enable_shared_from_this <A<T>>
{

    /* some parts in the class */
    void Run()
    {
        resolver_.async_resolve(host_, port_, boost::bind_front_handler(&A:on_resolve, this->shared_from_this());
    }
    /* ... */
};
```

I have tried std::enable_shared_from_this>::shared_from_this() and this->shared_from_this() and I did not call shared_from_this() function in a class constructor. If there are any ways to solve this error, please let me know.

Comment: Include the full error message in your question. Is `this>shared_from_this()` a typo?

Comment: Is the current instance (as referenced by `this`) managed by a valid `shared_ptr<A>`?  If not `shared_from_this` will fail (see [notes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this#Notes)).

Comment: I agree with the other commenters: there's a lot of unnecessary typos in your code. Code that can't possibly compile. Always try to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). See my answer for what it could look like

Comment: Also, because of the typos and because there was a comment "this occurs the error" I had assumed you had compilation errors. Luckily, my answer ALSO shows how to correctly use `std::make_shared` and/or `shared_from_this`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is wrong, [you're passing too many arguments](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_resolver/async_resolve.html). Instead, pass a single query parameter:

```
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query q{host_, port_};
    resolver_.async_resolve(q,
```

Next up, you can use either bind method you prefer:

```
    boost::bind(&A::on_resolve, this->shared_from_this(),
        boost::asio::placeholders::error(),
        boost::asio::placeholders::results())
```

Or not using bind at all:

```
    resolver_.async_resolve(q,
        [self=this->shared_from_this()](boost::system::error_code ec, boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::results_type eps) {
            self->on_resolve(ec, eps);
        }
    );
```

Or using the convenience helper from Beast:

```
    boost::beast::bind_front_handler(&A::on_resolve, this->shared_from_this())
```

### Live Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e9c3c05f5bfd3b0)</kbd>**

```
#include <memory> // for std::shared_from_this etc
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>                    // for boost::bind
#include <boost/beast/core/bind_handler.hpp> // for bind_front_handler

template<typename T>
class A: public std::enable_shared_from_this<A<T>>
{
  public:
    A(boost::asio::io_context& io, std::string host, std::string port)
        : resolver_(io), host_(host), port_(port) {}

    void Run()
    {
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query q{host_, port_};
        resolver_.async_resolve(q,
            boost::beast::bind_front_handler(&A::on_resolve, this->shared_from_this())
        );
        resolver_.async_resolve(q,
            boost::bind(&A::on_resolve, this->shared_from_this(),
                boost::asio::placeholders::error(),
                boost::asio::placeholders::results())
        );
        resolver_.async_resolve(q,
            [self=this->shared_from_this()](boost::system::error_code ec, boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::results_type eps) {
                self->on_resolve(ec, eps);
            }
        );
    }

  private:
    void on_resolve(boost::system::error_code ec, boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::results_type eps) {
        std::cout << "Resolved: (" << ec.message() << "):";
        for (auto& ep : eps) {
            std::cout << " " << ep.endpoint();
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver_;
    std::string host_, port_;
};

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context io;
    auto instance = std::make_shared<A<int> >(io, "localhost", "1234");
    instance->Run();

    io.run();
}
```

Prints (not on Coliru due to networking restrictions):

```
Resolved: (Success): 127.0.0.1:1234
Resolved: (Success): 127.0.0.1:1234
Resolved: (Success): 127.0.0.1:1234
```

Comment: Just on a sidenote, for connecting, prefer [`boost::asio::async_connect`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_connect.html) which will do the resolve for you.

Comment: Is the third code snippet supposed to be the same as the second? The fact you say "not using bind at all" suggests it might not (but rather that lambda from the live demo).